# D3 - Group Rows of Swimlane Data

Tags: d3.js

I am developing a swimlane diagram using D3 v4. The diagram is a planning aid depicting Tasks which are carried out over time. The Tasks are up the Y axis and time is along the X axis.

Here is some example data to help understand my problem:

Tasks

```
[
    {
        "id": "2a606884-d6b9-4ad1-a5ff-5c816c43fef6",
        "description": "Task 01",
        "start": "2017-11-07T02:00:00.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-11-07T08:00:00.000Z",
        "label": "Task 01",
        "taskTypeId": "0b936e39-49b9-4cc8-b5c5-b1f1338e9faf",
        "taskTypeDescription": "Walk the dog"
    },
    {
        "id": "6713025e-63e2-4ff3-8202-43e17c13431d",
        "description": "Task 02",
        "start": "2017-11-07T08:00:00.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-11-07T12:00:00.000Z",
        "label": "Task 02 02",
        "taskTypeId": "9af060ba-5abf-4627-8462-7c21281ab487",
        "taskTypeDescription": "Wash the car"
    },
    {
        "id": "ff071aa5-e14b-4b32-bd51-7cf079f4c876",
        "description": "Task 03",
        "start": "2017-11-07T12:00:00.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-11-07T14:00:00.000Z",
        "label": "Task 03",
        "taskTypeId": "8e6a8b11-0e23-4473-8795-ac74fc1efe07",
        "taskTypeDescription": "Make the beds"
    },
    {
        "id": "a84219e2-5da9-4119-915b-d84f35fda9d0",
        "description": "Task 04",
        "start": "2017-11-07T12:00:00.000Z",
        "finish": "2017-11-07T14:00:00.000Z",
        "label": "Task 04",
        "taskTypeId": "a065dfe2-2c68-4467-84a5-1fce7c34513b",
        "taskTypeDescription": "Wash up dishes"
    }
]
```

New TaskTypes array nested by Area:

```
[
    {
        "key": "Outdoor",
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "a97ad203-37e4-4fb8-8168-c3fdc1980d3d",
                "description": "Walk the dog",
                "areaId": "19952c5a-b762-4937-a613-6151c8cd9332",
                "areaDescription": "Outdoor"
            },
            {
                "id": "0b936e39-49b9-4cc8-b5c5-b1f1338e9faf",
                "description": "Wash the car",
                "areaId": "19952c5a-b762-4937-a613-6151c8cd9332",
                "areaDescription": "Outdoor"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "Indoor",
        "values": [
            {
                "id": "8632bd18-8968-4185-95f0-f093f7fc9a02",
                "description": "Make the beds",
                "areaId": "87d8f755-ef60-4cfa-9a4a-c94cff9f8a22",
                "areaDescription": "Indoor"
            },
            {
                "id": "8e6a8b11-0e23-4473-8795-ac74fc1efe07",
                "description": "Wash the dishes",
                "areaId": "87d8f755-ef60-4cfa-9a4a-c94cff9f8a22",
                "areaDescription": "Indoor"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far my diagram lists all the TaskTypes up the Y axis using a simple 1 dimensional array of TaskTypes. Each Task is then positioned, within its row for the Task's TaskType, along the X axis according to the start/finish of the Task. All good.

My yScale is currently like this:

```
this.yScale = d3
            .scaleBand()
            .domain(this.taskTypeDescriptions)
            .rangeRound([0, this.chartHeight])
            .padding(padding);
```

...where `this.taskTypeDescriptions` is a simple 1 dimensional array of TaskTypes.

Now I have grouped TaskTypes by Area. In my example data above there are 2 Areas: Outdoor and Indoor. I want to visually group the rows of TaskType by their parent Area.

This appears to be like a grouped bar chart except that all the examples I have seen of these have the same second tier of data repeated for each primary group of data. In my scenario I have many discrete TaskTypes, none of them repeated, but I still want them grouped by their Area. Is this possible at all?

Any suggestions or thoughts very welcome. Thanks.

Comment: You can simply sort your domain array by the area.

Comment: Good reply Gerardo, thanks. This would get me part of the way, however I need to visually separate the groups of `TaskTypes`. Using my example data, down my Y axis I want to see a group heading 'Outdoor' followed by the outdoor rows of `TaskTypes`, of which there may be 5, then I want to see a group heading 'Indoor' followed by the indoor rows of `TaskTypes` of which there may be say 8.

Comment: That's exactly what the sorting will do.

Comment: I can visualise that sorting would place all of the Outdoor TaskTypes together and all of the Indoor TaskTypes together, but would they not be presented as a single, continuous list of TaskTypes? I want a gap between the Outdoor TaskTypes and the Indoor TaskTypes with a group heading.

Comment: That is also simple: just create two y scales, one for outdoor and one for indoor, with different ranges and domains.

Comment: That makes sense, a separate Y scale for the Areas and the TaskTypes. I still can't see how the rows of TaskTypes will have space between each group? Remember there will not be the same number of items in each group.

Comment: Well, I can't help you more than this, since you didn't provide a [MCVE].